# Covert Date String into Date Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a date object which has been saved as a string to a Cookie called `LastDate`

Reading the string from the cookie I get

`$.cookie('LastDate');` =  "Fri Jan 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"

How can I convert this back into a date object in my code? I have tried to do a `Date.parse` but that just returns seconds

`Date.parse($.cookie('LastDate'));`
= 1388703600000

Is there a way to convert this string back to an actual date object?

Thanks

Comment: You have one [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor for that: `new Date($.cookie('LastDate'))`

Comment: What do you want to get back?

Comment: @Adriano - thanks dude, not sure why I did not see that

Comment: why the negative vote? question was structured correctly, and I did not know the answer and now I do?

Comment: Probably because the answer could have easily been gleaned from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 1):

To convert dateString back to Date object you just need to create a new object with dateString as parameter. In your case:

```
var dateObj = new Date($.cookie('LastDate'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use bellow code:

var newDate = new Date();

newDate = new Date($.cookie('LastDate'));

Thanks